# XSLT duplicate items in a hierarchy transfomation

Tags: xml, xslt, hierarchical-data

i'm new in the forum so forgive me for some error of style and language not being english.
My problem is that i have an output in xml from a select on db and i would like to trasform, by xslt, this flat structure on a hierarchical structure.
My xslt work fine and do the hierarchy right but there is a problem that duplicates all the items and makes that copies a root element
This is the xml output from the select on db :

```
<cdcDbSet xmlns="http://eos.mcr.com/cdc/anagrafica/ds">
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>17</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>5</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>testGP</cdcName>
      <order>1</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>15</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Caserta</cdcName>
      <order>1</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>5</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>2</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Progetti</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>16</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>testGP</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>18</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>5</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>testGPS</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>11</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>figlio</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>10</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>pippo</cdcName>
      <order>3</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>6</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>5</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>EOS</cdcName>
      <order>3</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>3</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Milano</cdcName>
      <order>4</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>7</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>3</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>l</cdcName>
      <order>4</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>14</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>15</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>testMOD</cdcName>
      <order>4</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>8</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>pippo</cdcName>
      <order>5</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>4</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Napoli</cdcName>
      <order>5</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
   <cdcEntity>
      <idCdc>9</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>4</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>cccc</cdcName>
      <order>6</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
   </cdcEntity>
</cdcDbSet>
```

This is the xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:nsc="http://eos.mcr.com/cdc/anagrafica/ds" version="1.0">
<xsl:key match="/nsc:cdcDbSet/nsc:cdcEntity" name="nodeChildren" use="nsc:idCdcParent"/>
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/nsc:cdcDbSet/nsc:cdcEntity/nsc:idCdcParent"/>
<xsl:template match="nsc:cdcDbSet">
    <cdcList xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="nsc:cdcEntity[nsc:idCdcParent=$root]"/>
    </cdcList>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="nsc:cdcEntity">
    <cdc xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <idCdc>
            <xsl:value-of select="nsc:idCdc"/>
        </idCdc>
        <idCdcParent>
            <xsl:value-of select="nsc:idCdcParent"/>
        </idCdcParent>
        <cdcName>
            <xsl:value-of select="nsc:cdcName"/>
        </cdcName>
        <order>
            <xsl:value-of select="nsc:order"/>
        </order>
        <isUsed>
            <xsl:value-of select="nsc:isUsed"/>
        </isUsed>
        <cdcList>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('nodeChildren',nsc:idCdc)"/>
        </cdcList>
    </cdc>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the transformed xml :

```
<cdcList xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
         xmlns:nsc="http://eos.mcr.com/cdc/anagrafica/ds">
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>17</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>5</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>testGP</cdcName>
      <order>1</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>15</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Caserta</cdcName>
      <order>1</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>14</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>15</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>testMOD</cdcName>
            <order>4</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
      </cdcList>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>5</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>2</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Progetti</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>17</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>5</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>testGP</cdcName>
            <order>1</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>18</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>5</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>testGPS</cdcName>
            <order>2</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>6</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>5</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>EOS</cdcName>
            <order>3</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
      </cdcList>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>16</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>testGP</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>18</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>5</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>testGPS</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>11</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>figlio</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>10</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>pippo</cdcName>
      <order>3</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>6</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>5</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>EOS</cdcName>
      <order>3</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>3</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Milano</cdcName>
      <order>4</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>7</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>3</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>l</cdcName>
            <order>4</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
      </cdcList>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>7</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>3</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>l</cdcName>
      <order>4</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>14</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>15</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>testMOD</cdcName>
      <order>4</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>8</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>pippo</cdcName>
      <order>5</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>4</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Napoli</cdcName>
      <order>5</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>9</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>4</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>cccc</cdcName>
            <order>6</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
      </cdcList>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>9</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>4</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>cccc</cdcName>
      <order>6</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
```

As you can see there are some items that are repeated and i would like to remove it.
For example the item cdc with the idCdc=17 is under the cdcList and under the cdc with idCdc=5
I have tried to modify the xslt without good result.
Thank you to everyone try to help me.

P.s.: i expect to see something like this :

```
    <cdcList xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xmlns:nsc="http://eos.mcr.com/cdc/anagrafica/ds">
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>1</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>0</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Roma</cdcName>
      <order>1</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>4</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>testMOD</cdcName>
            <order>4</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>5</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>testMOD</cdcName>
            <order>4</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>6</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>testMOD</cdcName>
            <order>4</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList>
                <cdc>
                    <idCdc>7</idCdc>
                    <idCdcParent>6</idCdcParent>
                    <cdcName>testMODChild</cdcName>
                    <order>4</order>
                    <isUsed>false</isUsed>
                    <cdcList/>
                </cdc>
            </cdcList>
         </cdc>
      </cdcList>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>2</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>0</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Progetti</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>8</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>2</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>testGP</cdcName>
            <order>1</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>9</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>2</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>testGPS</cdcName>
            <order>2</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>10</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>2</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>EOS</cdcName>
            <order>3</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
      </cdcList>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>3</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>0</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Milano</cdcName>
      <order>4</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>11</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>3</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>l</cdcName>
            <order>4</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
      </cdcList>
   </cdc>
</cdcList>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output you expect to see in this case? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/nsc:cdcDbSet/nsc:cdcEntity/nsc:idCdcParent"/>
```

This does not select a single node, let alone the root node, or even the ID of the root node.

It selects **all** `<nsc:idCdcParent>` elements. Together with this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="nsc:cdcEntity[nsc:idCdcParent=$root]"/>
```

where `[nsc:idCdcParent=$root]` always is true, because all `<nsc:idCdcParent>` are in `$root`, and the recursive step

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('nodeChildren',nsc:idCdc)"/>
```

You go through the input document multiple times, resulting in duplicated output.

---

Assuming that the root node has the ID 1, this produces a correctly nested tree.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:nsc="http://eos.mcr.com/cdc/anagrafica/ds"
    xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
    exclude-result-prefixes="nsc"
>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="nodesByParent" match="nsc:cdcEntity" use="nsc:idCdcParent"/>

    <xsl:template match="nsc:cdcDbSet">
        <cdcList>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('nodesByParent', 1)"/>
        </cdcList>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="nsc:cdcEntity">
        <cdc>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy-local" select="
                nsc:idCdc|nsc:idCdcParent|nsc:cdcName|nsc:order|nsc:isUsed
            " />
            <cdcList>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('nodesByParent', nsc:idCdc)"/>
            </cdcList>
        </cdc>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-local">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note

- the top-level default `xmlns` declaration, so you don't need to repeat yourself in the stylesheet body
- the `exclude-result-prefixes` attribute
- reduced duplication through the use of a template for outputting any element with the same local name

Result:

```
<cdcList xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>15</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Caserta</cdcName>
      <order>1</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>14</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>15</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>testMOD</cdcName>
            <order>4</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
      </cdcList>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>16</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>testGP</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>11</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>figlio</cdcName>
      <order>2</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>10</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>pippo</cdcName>
      <order>3</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>3</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Milano</cdcName>
      <order>4</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>7</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>3</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>l</cdcName>
            <order>4</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
      </cdcList>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>8</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>pippo</cdcName>
      <order>5</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList/>
   </cdc>
   <cdc>
      <idCdc>4</idCdc>
      <idCdcParent>1</idCdcParent>
      <cdcName>Napoli</cdcName>
      <order>5</order>
      <isUsed>false</isUsed>
      <cdcList>
         <cdc>
            <idCdc>9</idCdc>
            <idCdcParent>4</idCdcParent>
            <cdcName>cccc</cdcName>
            <order>6</order>
            <isUsed>false</isUsed>
            <cdcList/>
         </cdc>
      </cdcList>
   </cdc>
</cdcList>
```

Answer (score 0):

This trasformation work very well but if i wanted an output without the cdc item and with the square brackets in every cdcList like this one?

```
{
"cdcList": [{
        "idCdc": 2,
        "idCdcParent": null,
        "cdcName": "Roma",
        "order": 1,
        "isUsed": false,
        "cdcList": [{
            "idCdc": 5,
            "idCdcParent": 2,
            "cdcName": "Progetti",
            "order": 2,
            "isUsed": false,
            "cdcList": [{
                    "idCdc": 17,
                    "idCdcParent": 5,
                    "cdcName": "testGP",
                    "order": 1,
                    "isUsed": false,
                    "cdcList": null
                },
                {
                    "idCdc": 18,
                    "idCdcParent": 5,
                    "cdcName": "testGPS",
                    "order": 2,
                    "isUsed": false,
                    "cdcList": null
                }
            ]



        }]
    },
    {
        "idCdc": 3,
        "idCdcParent": null,
        "cdcName": "Milano",
        "order": 4,
        "isUsed": false,
        "cdcList": [{

            "idCdc": 7,
            "idCdcParent": 3,
            "cdcName": "l",
            "order": 4,
            "isUsed": false,
            "cdcList": null
        }]
    },
    {
        "idCdc": 4,
        "idCdcParent": null,
        "cdcName": "Napoli",
        "order": 5,
        "isUsed": false,
        "cdcList": [{

            "idCdc": 9,
            "idCdcParent": 4,
            "cdcName": "cccc",
            "order": 6,
            "isUsed": false,
            "cdcList": null
        }]
    }
]
```

}

I need to implement this json in Angular5 and the Tree Component library need this format of output